# Change username for Azure Sendgrid created from Azure Market place

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-marketplace

Is it possible to change the username of your Sendgrid account in Azure after it is created from the market place?

Our account was created a few years ago and the username is gibberish so when sending emails the username is referenced and I want to be able to change this to something meaningful.

I have contacted Sendgrid and this is out of their hands since it was created through Azure and Azure doesn't let me edit this name.
Currently, we are on the free plan but if needed we can change to a paid plan if this feature is available but I cannot find any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, Azure does not support change Sendgrid user name. Also, you could not use specify the user name when you create Sendgrid account. The user naming rule is `azure_***@azure.com`

The user name is used to login Sendgrid management Portal. I don't think you need to modify it. You could modify your sender mail address on Sendgrid Portal.