# Azure market place Sendgrid username

Tags: azure, sendgrid

The Microsoft documentation [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email#create-a-sendgrid-account) says that once an account has been set up you can see the SendGrid credentials by clicking on the key icon.  This seems to have disappeared from the Azure portal.  How can I find the SendGrid username for this service.  I believe it is in the format of azure***@azure.com (see [change username for ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426798/change-username-for-azure-sendgrid-created-from-azure-market-place)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar issue and took a guess to see if Azure CLI would give it to me and it does.

In the portal use the cloud shell option, this icon top right:

[image]

Change the shell type from PowerShell to Bash, if you have multiple accounts then you will need to select the right account

```
az account show
```

If not in the right account (**UPDATE** - if you have permissions to access all accounts then you won't need to switch accounts so you can skip to the final bit)

```
az account list
az account set -s <id of relevant subscription>
```

Then on the SendGrid resource blade go to Properties and copy the Resource ID and then run

```
az resource show --ids /subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Sendgrid.Email/accounts/xxxxx
```

using your resource id obviously and in the output you will see the SendGrid username

Comment: Simon, I think there was a temporary issue with the Azure platform as I can now open up SendGrid by selecting the Mange icon.  However, I tried you suggestion and it worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @dmb_acunim Ah cool and thanks for letting me know, saves me having to remember those usernames!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you forgot the username and password of your SendGrid account, so you can not reset your password via the button `Reset Password` on Azure portal, as the figure below.

[image]

On Azure portal, there seems to be username and email registered when account created in the tab `Export template`, as the figure below.

[image]

You can try to use it to reset password, and then to manage your API keys in SendGrid portal.

Comment: Currently the Manage link doesn't auto log you in and the reset password requires you to know the hidden username, see my response

Comment: Further note, the email in the exported template is where the password reset link will be sent but is not the username you need to request it sadly!

Answer (score 0):

The one provided by Simon should answer your question rightly. To supplement his answer, we can also just copy ResourceID section from properties like highlighted in yellow marker: [image: copy ResourceID section in Azure management portal]

and run the below command in our local command prompt once we have installed Azure CLI in our local system:

```
az resource show --ids <Copied ResourceID>
```

which translates to

```
az resource show --ids/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Sendgrid.Email/accounts/xxxxx
```

**Advantage**: This does not require us to try Bash Script in the Azure Cloud Shell (which requires configuration of an explicit storage account)